Help on deriving the generalized time shift $Δt(Θ)$ for the Michelson-Morley experiment
I am working on deriving the general equation for the time shift as a function of theta for a generalized case of the Michelson-Morley experiment. It should be in the following form when completed:
$$Δt(Θ) = (v^2/c^3) * \cos(2Θ)$$
I am unsure how to proceed with simplifying the expression to obtain cos(2Θ). I have been using vsin(Θ) and vcos(Θ) for the components of the aether wind velocity in the direction of the arm length l. l1 and l2 are equivalent. Any help on how to perform this derivation to get it into the above form would be helpful. Thank you.

